# Cocos2D getChild caused not declared in scope error

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, objective-c++

When trying to compile the following code for iphone in xcode

```
void removeGrid(int x,int y) {
    //for(id *item in self) {
        //if(item.position ==  ccp(x*32, y*32)) {
        //  printf("good");
        //}
        //printf("%@",item);
//  }
    char rrs[8];
    sprintf(rrs,"01%d%d",x/32,y/32);
    int aTag = [[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:rrs length:sizeof(rrs) encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] intValue];
    //NSAssert( aTag != kCCNodeTagInvalid, @"Invalid tag");

    CCNode *child = [self getChildByTag:aTag]; //here it is simply getting a single chil

    if (child == nil)
        CCLOG(@"cocos2d: removeChildByTag: child not found!");
    else
        [self removeChild:child cleanup:true];
}
```

The compiler says "self  was not declared in this scope". I'm new to objc and cocos2d, but this seems to be the way most tutorials access objects in the scene. Am I missing something?

Comment: What is your class declared under? What class does it inherit from?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. This turned out to be one of Xcode's quirks. Since the function declaration was in c++, it was not able to access objective c self functions for some reason. Changing the declaration to an objective c allowed it to access all the functions. Doesn't make much sense to me, but it now works fine.

For those of you wondering, yes, the file had a .mm extension.